# Android App Upgrading and Warning

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, warnings

I got an warning sign in my Google Play Developer Account.
Warning Message was:

> Please migrate your app(s) to Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher as soon
>   as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
>   Beginning May 9, 2016, Google Play will block publishing of any new
>   apps or updates that use pre-4.1.1 versions of Apache Cordova. The
>   vulnerabilities were addressed in Apache Cordova 4.1.1. If you’re
>   using a 3rd party library that bundles Apache Cordova, you’ll need to
>   upgrade it to a version that bundles Apache Cordova 4.1.1 or later. To
>   confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version to the
>   Developer Console and check back after five hours. If the app hasn’t
>   been correctly upgraded, we will display a warning.

After that I update cordova and my android  app. And also upload to the play developer account. It was successfully uploaded and publish. But the warning sign is still there. Need help from experts.

Comment: "To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version to the Developer Console and **check back after five hours**." Has it been 5 hours since?

Comment: Yes already, five hours. Uploaded and publish successfully. But warning sign still visible. I have no idea, what's going on!!

Comment: If the warning is still visible after the update has been published then send a mail to Google support.